# Get name of code section in Matlab script

Tags: matlab

I have a script (actually a test script used for script based unit tests) which is divided into sections of the type

```
%% test foo
code

%% test bar
more code
```

How do I retrieve the name of a section (in any form, e.g. `foo`, `test foo`, `TestFoo` or whatever Matlab makes out of a section name) from inside my script (i.e. the place where I have written `code`).

Comment: I'll be surprised if that's possible. You can put each section in a different script and use [`mfilename`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mfilename.html)

Comment: So the desired result is all the section names, e.g. `test foo` and `test bar` ? Please clarify

Comment: @Paolo At the place <code> i would like to get "test foo" and at the place  <more code> i would like to get "test bar".

Comment: @tommsch so you essentially want to get the comment of the section which is active, i e. where the cursor is?

Comment: @Paolo Yes, thats what i want.

Comment: @tommsch See my solution

Comment: @tommsch Does the solution provided by Christian resolve your question?

Comment: @Paolo Yes. I was busy so I only could test it yesterday - so the delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I have no Matlab on this computer. So the code is untested. But I guess with the code snippet below you should be able to do what you are trying.

It's a little bit hacky, but it's Matlab.

```
function section_name = get_current_section_name()

ds = dbstack();

execution_file = ds(2).file;
execution_line = ds(2).line;

fid = fopen(execution_file);

section_name = "";
current_line_number = 1;

tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    if startsWith(tline, "%%")
        section_name = tline;
    end

    if execution_line == current_line_number
        return
    end
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    current_line = current_line + 1;
end

fclose(fid)

% case: not found
section_name = "";

end
```

And on your desired position you should be fine if you just call

```
section_name = get_current_section_name()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution.
Given the following code:

```
%% test foo
code


%% test bar
more code

%% test baz
other code
```

You can obtain the comment of the active live script as follows:

```
>> X = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive; % Get MATLAB editor
>> editorText = X.Text; % Get editor text
>> n = X.Selection(1); % Get line number on which cursor is
>> all_lines = regexp(editorText,'\n','split'); % Get all lines of editor
>> for line = all_lines(n:-1:1) % Iterate backwards from starting lne
>>   if contains(line,'%%') % If the line contains a comment, extract string and exit loop
>>     match = regexp(line,'%% (.+)$','tokens','once')
>>     break
>>   end
>> end
```

`match` is a cell with the desired content. If your cursor is in the first code section, `match{1}` contains `test foo`. If the cursor is in the second block, `test bar` and finally `test baz` for the last block.

---

How it works:

First we get the active MATLAB editor and the position of the cursor. Then, we split on newline `\n` to obtain all of the lines in the editor. From the current line, we iterate backwards to identify the first line which has the comment, which contains the desired string.

Comment: But this doesn't get the section name above the code currently being executed, unless you execute the code through the "evaluate current section" button in the editor. If you just run the script by typing its name at the command prompt, what will it do?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, that's right. According to OP's comment that's what he wants.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yeah I see what you mean. For doing that during execution of a script OP should use the other solution.

Comment: @Paolo, Now, finally, I understand your question. No, that was not what I wanted. But I will keep that in mind, maybe I need it later anytime.